# Use $dateFormat INT in models in codeigniter4

Tags: php, model, timestamp, codeigniter-4

Reading the documentation of CodeIgniter4 (Models), i found this.

[image]

I tried use a timestamps with a type date of int, but this not working because at updated the column "updated_at" it is 0. My model is:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UserModel extends eCrisisModel{
    
    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    
    protected $returnType = 'array';
    protected $useSoftDeletes = true;

    protected $allowedFields = ["login", "pass", "about_me", "utc"];

    protected $useTimestamps = true;
    protected $createdField = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField = 'updated_at';
    protected $deletedField = 'deleted_at';
    protected $dateFormat = 'int';
}

?>
```

The eCrisisModel is a abstract class extends of Model class:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

// existentialCrisis
abstract class eCrisisModel extends Model{

    protected $prefix = '';
    protected $exists = false;
    protected $builder;
    public function __construct(...$params){
        parent::__construct(...$params);
        //"I am therefore I think"
        if(!$this->db->tableExists($this->prefix.$this->table)){
            $this->creatingMe();
            $this->exists = true;
        }
        $this->builder = $this->db->table($this->table);
    }

    public function creatingMe(){
        //...
    }
}

?>
```

The controller where it is executed is:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class Test extends Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->UserModel = model('App\Models\UserModel');
        $this->SettingModel = model('App\Models\SettingModel');
    }

    public function index(){
        $data = [
                'login' => 'jiji',
                'pass'  => password_hash("passss",PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
                'about_me'  => 'xd',
                'utc' => -2.75
        ];

        $this->UserModel->builder->where('id', 1);
        $this->UserModel->builder->update($data);
    }
}

?>
```

And the database after of the update is:
[image]

Describe table;
[image]

Which is my error ? why the system not recording the update timestamp?

Comment: change the database columns `created_at` etc to type `datetime`

Comment: but i want use int

Comment: Is the *column's* datatype `int`? What is the output of `describe user;`

Comment: @parttimeturtle i updated the question with the pic of describe of table